# How to upload my iOS app to particular store only

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app for my client. He want to upload app in australian store only.i want to upload that app to australian stores. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the app on iTunes connect you can select the pricing and availability per region.

In iTunes Connect go to "Rights and Pricing".

Then you'll get this...

[image]